# How to assign hardware output to a variable in codesys?

Tags: plc, codesys

I'm actually using the Ecostruxure skin on codesys, trying to attach the output of a Modicon encoder to determine the speed a motor should go.

However, I can't figure out how to grab the variable that would correspond to that data. Any help appreciated.

The screenshots below indicate where I'm stuck. I need to create a variable of type `ENC_REF_M262` however double clicking on the device does not take me to a screen I can map it with like what I've seen on a number of other devices. Obviously something I'm missing. The linking between this physical device and actually getting data from it is the part I'm struggling with.

[image]
[image]

edit: The system seems to have now correctly accepted the settings when before the reference to the variable `Incremental Encoder` would not be found. Seems to take a while to catch up.
[image]

Comment: What codesys? 2.3 or 3.5?

Comment: 3.5. Found it on their website.

Comment: Just an FYI, if you are on Ecostruxure Machine Expert, it should be using the CODESYS 3.5.12 compiler. Anyways, first you should find out what protocol does that Modicon Encoder output: Is it Digital or Analog wire? Is it Modbus RTU or Modbus TCP? Or maybe something else, like CANopen or OPC?

Comment: Using the M262, it's got an encoder port directly on it which I assume is P2P and shouldn't require a bus (particularly as the hardware when loaded in doesn't give you that option).

Comment: From your screenshot, it looks like it is mapped to the variable `Incremental_Encoder` as writen in the `Variable` box. Have you tried accessing it?